Difference between clicking the words "Title*", "Body*", and "Rev" on the edit page
If you click on the word "Title*" on the edit page (Chrome for Android) you can type in your desired title to edit the previous one. If you click on the white background to its right nothing happens (which is good)

But if you accidentally click on the white background on the right side of the words "Body*" or "Rev" they are activated!


The behavior should be consistent, and the words "Body*" and "Rev" should be clickable only when we touch the texts themselves just like the case of the word "Title*" or vice-versa.

TLDR; We hear you and understand the UX issue especially for mobile users but we have bigger fishes to fry.
We can agree that clicking on a seemly white random spot on the screen and being focused somewhere can be annoying especially on mobile where you don’t have a lot of real estate and you have to touch the screen (and trigger a click event) to scroll. Not only does this bring focus to the input field but also brings up the mobile keyboard reducing further the real estate. There's a valid UX issue to consider especially for people using mobiles.
Looking at a few other websites, it seems to be mixed on wether this is common practice or not.
Having the entire area be clickable is currently the case for most of the forms on the site. If we change it on the Edit page, it should be changed everywhere. Based on the amount of work, how many users are likely affected (mostly mobile) and how "annoying" this issue is for those users, we have decided our efforts are better suited on fixing other issues.

Thank you for your answer. I have also asked another question about a similar issue on the "Hot Network Questions" and "Related".
